# Using relations in MySQL

Tags: mysql, relationship, relation

Let's say that I have the following tables:

```
Elements:
  (int) ID
  (int) Name_id

Names:
  (int) ID
  (varchar) Name
```

The `Elements.Name_id` has an internal relation with `Names.id`. The user enters an element name in a html form. Then a php script inserts the element name to the Elements table. And here comes my question:

Is it possible to specify the element name instead of the element `name_id` in the insert query? If not I will have to:

```
SELECT `ID` FROM `Names` WHERE `Names`.`Name` LIKE "$php_variable";
...
INSERT INTO `Elements` SET `Name` = "$php_variable";
```

Of course the second $php_variable is a result from the previous query.

Comment: `INSERT INTO Elements (Name_id) SELECT ID FROM Names WHERE Name = ?`.

Comment: @eggyal Good enough, thank you.

Comment: What should happen if there is no match to the name entered by the user?

Comment: I'm confused as to why\how you have a relationship between `Elements.Name_id` and `Names.id`.  One is an `int` and the other is a `varchar`.

Comment: @PaulF The HTML form is an option based form - there will always be a match to the name entered by the user

Comment: @MartinParkin You're right, I've corrected the error.

Comment: Do duplicates matter ?

Comment: @PaulF No, the name is unique

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, I meant duplicates in the Elements table rather than Names table

Comment: @PaulF The ID is unique, the name_id is not. So there can be many rows with the same name_id, but always with a different element.id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

```
insert into elements(name)
    select n.name
    from names n
    where n.id = $php_variable;
```

Now, having said this, *do not take this approach*.  Your data structure is wrong.  You want to connect to `names.id`, not `names.name`, in most cases.  (There are some exceptions where copying the name might be one solution for a slowly changing dimension, but I doubt that is your use-case.)

So, fix the data structure.  The create table statements would look like:

```
create table names (
    name_id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(255) unique
);

create table elements (
    element_id int auto_increment primary key,
    name_id int,
    foreign key (name_id) references names(name_id)
);
```

Then use an explicit `JOIN` to get the name when you need it.

Note:  I changed the ids of the table to be "tablename_Id".  This is not required, but I find it helpful to have foreign keys and primary keys have the same names.

Comment: It will be more helpful if you change ordering of table creation as in given order it will throw error....